# Managing keyboard with scroll view

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I am currently taking this course about scroll View from raywenderlich. There is a lesson on how to add observers to the notification center to track when the keyBoard shows. Here is how the code looks.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)


func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    adjustKeyboardInset(false, notification: notification)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    adjustKeyboardInset(true, notification: notification)
}

func adjustKeyboard(isShown: Bool, notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let adjustedHeight = keyboardFrame.height * (isShown ? 1 : -1) + 20

    mySV.contentInset.bottom += adjustedHeight
    mySV.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustedHeight
}
```

This works correctly for the first time the text field is clicked. However when you keep clicking the textField it keeps adding space to it.

Would appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better not using "+=" operation. The alternative solution could be like:

```
var originalBottom:CGFloat = 0.0
var originalIndicatorBottom:CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    originalBottom = mySV.contentInset.bottom.constant
    originalIndicatorBottom:CGFloat = mySV.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom.constant
}

//......    

func adjustKeyboard(isShown: Bool, notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let adjustedHeight = keyboardFrame.height + 20

    if isShown {
        mySV.contentInset.bottom = originalBottom + adjustedHeight
        mySV.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = originalIndicatorBottom + adjustedHeight
    }
    else
    {
       mySV.contentInset.bottom = originalBottom 
       mySV.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = originalIndicatorBottom 
    }

}
```